# Update entity columns iterating through col list using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I can get column list from the table using LINQ like this:

```
OrderDataContext ctx = new OrderDataContext();
var cols = ctx.Mapping.MappingSource
                        .GetModel( typeof( OrderDataContext ) )
                        .GetMetaType( typeof( ProductInformation ) )
                        .DataMembers;
```

This gives me the list of columns, so I can do this:

```
foreach ( var col in cols )
{
    // Get the value of this column from another table
    GetPositionForThisField( col.Name );
}
```

So this all works, I can iterate through column list and pull the values for those columns from an another table (since the column names are the keys in that another table), so I don't have to do switch....or lot of if...then...

Now the question:

After I get these values, how do I populate the entity in order to save it back? I would normally go like this:

```
ProductInformation info = new ProductInformation();
info.SomeField1 = val1;
info.SomeField2 = val2;

ctx.ProductInformation.InsertOnSubmit( info );
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

But how to use the same column collection from above to populate the columns while iterating over that, when there is no such thing as:

```
info["field1"].Value = val1;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the object that you want to modofy, set the property and call SubmitChanges. There is no need to create a new object and insert it. The Context tracks your changed properties and generates the update statement accordingly. In your case you may want to set the properties via reflection rather than manually since you are reading them from another table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use reflection. Assuming you can get the `PropertyInfo` from the metadata:

```
PropertyInfo property = GetPropertyForThisField(col.Name);
property.SetValue(info, val1, null);
```